# Connecting docker container application to remote database server

Tags: docker, devops

How can I make my spring boot application running inside docker containers connect to postgres database that is running in remote server (non-docker environment). Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.3"
  services:
    app1:
       image: repo/app1:latest
       ports:
           - 8000:8000
       restart: always
       network_mode: "host"
       extra_hosts:
           - 'postgresdb:192.168.2.50'

   app2:
       image: repo/app2:latest
       ports:
           - 8001:8001
       restart: always
       network_mode: "host"
       extra_hosts:
           - 'postgresdb:192.168.2.50'
```

IP of remote PostgreSQL database machine is: `192.168.2.50`(hostname: `postgresdb`)

I am using `network_mode: "host"` option and works without any problem but I believe this would defeat the purpose of using docker network.  What other options are available to make this work without using network_mode? IP address and necessary ports on both, the docker machine and remote database server, are all whitelisted and have access through the firewalls.

Comment: Did you try running it in a default bridge network? I don't see why it wouldn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such implementation, obviously will not work.
Since your database deployed remotely, the only working solution will be provided with environment variables.

```
version: "3.3"
  services:
    app1:
     image: repo/app1:latest
     ports:
       - 8000:8000
     restart: always
     network_mode: "host"
     environment:
       - DBHOST: "192.168.2.50"
```

All you need in your application is to use this variable.
Python example:

```
dbhost = os.getenv("DBHOST")
```

Comment: HI @Rockvlv , Sorry for the late response. I was able to work on this project just recently. Although I was deploying the application differently using a centralized configurations, adding environment variable in docker-compose helped resolving the issue. So, I accept your answer. Thank you for your response.